# Override Backbutton with dialog

Tags: android, back-button

I have a single activity. When the user wants to close this activity using the back-button, I want to display a dialog, whether the user is sure and some other options.

Overriding the button is not problem, but really finishing the app from the dialog is the issue.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.i(tag, "Pushed BACK button by onKeyDown");
    }

    try {
        showFinishDialog();
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

This opens the dialog (showFinishDialog()), but I do not know what to call within the dialog to finally really finish my activity. I tried public functions like onBackPressed and onDestroy, but no success.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: show what you have tried to finish the activity

Answer (score 2):

Override `onBackPressed()`. You can achieve your goal by following code which overrides the back button and popup the dialog box.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
                        //Do your coding here. For Positive button

                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just write down

```
finish();
```

wherever you want to finish your activity.

Like if you want to finish on a button click

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
finish();
}
```